# Pedigree disease risk calculation IRL - how difficult/expensive?

Tags: genetics, dna, genetic-predisposition

The probability of a child being affected by genetic diseases like [Spinal muscular atrophy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spinal_muscular_atrophy) or [Canavan disease](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canavan_disease) (and many other) depends solely on the parents being carriers of such disease.

Suppose we have biological materials of both parents. How difficult and how expensive (or, rather, what procedures would be involved in that, since the costs would likely vary country to country) would it be test potential parents for a large enough list of genetic diseases and calculate the probability of their offspring being affected by it?

Comment: Although extremely unromantic, I believe this would be quite a useful service. I was not able to find companies providing it.

Comment: Testing is usually cheap and easy.  The hard, expensive part is usually figuring out which mutation causes the disease, so we know what to test for.